# dart: How to show data from mysql to browser by use sqljocky connector

Tags: mysql, dart

Everybody can tell me How to show data from mysql to browser by use sqljocky connector.

I guess "dart:io and dart:html" that is problem.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

SQLJocky is running at the server side (with Dart VM). It doesn't limit what approach to show the data to any client, including browser. However, it means you have to handle it by yourself. Its role is similar to JDBC in Java.